# Embedded devices hardware comparison

Tags: hardware, embedded

Not sure if this is a 100% serverfault compliant question, but here goes:

I need to choose the hardware for an embedded device I plan to develop and I'm looking for tips.

Ideally there'd be a comparison matrix website, or even just a comprehensive list. I can't find anything decent, so what do you guys use?

---

EDIT: General consensus is that I'm not being specific enough. What I want is:

- a device small enough to wear comfortably,
- that can run off batteries
- that has at least two USB slots
- and that can by programmed with a fairly standard language

Obviously these aren't hard ans fast rules, but would make things easier. Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's too vague a question, the range of embedded devices is huge, and the hardware that makes sense depends on the application.  I'd look at some of the magazine websites to get started:  Embedded Systems Design, EDN, EETimes

And google embedded systems design to get pages like this one:

[Embedded System Design (a textbook)](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/)

Comment: Sorry about the vagueness. I appreciate that the range is huge - that's kinda my problem. I didn't think Serverfault was an appropriate place to ask whether anyone knew of hardware which would meet my specific requirements - do you think I'd get any useful answers?

Answer (score 2):

The world of embedded systems covers so much territory that you can't possibly create a single comparison chart. Give some clues as to what you are doing and what sort of processing power you need, and perhaps a narrow range can be compared.

Embedded systems covers everything from tiny little 8 bit micros in the PIC and 8051 families all the way up to full-fledged PCs in industrial cases. Narrow the search parameters for us, and we'll help you pick something out.

Answer (score 1):

this question brings to mind this company :  [LogicSupply](http://www.logicsupply.com/)

Answer (score 1):

What do we use to do *what*?  To put a blinking LED on a greeting card? Or to run Jurassic Park?